# Transfer ResultSet from Java to JSP using Ajax

Tags: java, spring

I have a `ResultSet` in my Java class. How can I transfer this `ResultSet` to a `jsp` without using scriptlets?

Comment: No, you don't want to transfer `ResultSets` anywhere. You're supposed to read them, store the values and close them. It's not an object you're supposed to pass around to different parts of code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a spring controller method and returning the JSP for a request.

You can set any object into the ModelView and return the ModelView object and spring will set all these objects into the response.

```
@Controller
public ClassName {
  ....

@RequestMapping(value = "/ex/foos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView postFoos(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("myjsppage");
    model.addObject("msg", "hello world");
    return model;
}
```

Meanwhile in the JSP, you can use this.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
     <h1>Spring MVC Hello World Example</h1>
     <h2>${msg}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you can set any objects into the modelView. I just gave this String as an example. You can use JSTL and EL in the JSP to iterate/view value of objects.

These links might help

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-coc-modelmap

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: Thanks for the link you have given me....I am retrieving data from database using java class....and now i am storing it into result set ...How to I display my data in 'jsp' page using spring.....Right now I am displaying the data using result set by calling java function directly from 'jsp'....but i want to display data without result set.